# Issues with removing an old internet wire from a house I will demolish

Tags: property

I have some tree limbs I need to cut but there is a wire for internet under the limb going to a house I own from a utility pole. I will be demolishing this house next year. I called the local internet company to get it removed, but I'm not a customer, will not become one and there is no potential service to this house in the future, so there isn't a lot of motivation for the company to schedule this. I have been waiting for this to be scheduled for over a month. Is it a big deal if I just cut this myself? Its definitely not an electrical wire. I already had the electrical source removed.

Comment: It certainly depends on your location, etc., but I'd recommend minor caution, since I've had it happen that an internet company (or the phone company, years ago), declared that they owned all the hardware, and someone was just leasing it... even if/when they just throw it in recycling when you do bring something back...

Comment: If you are concerned with "cutting" it, simply disconnect it from your house, coil it up, and leave the coil at the edge of your property. No damage or loss to them, and you will have accomplished your objective.

Comment: This definitely borders on the issue of asking for specific legal advice, however, it can be structured in fashion to avoid such issues. I strongly recommend providing as much location information as you can. For example, in NJ the rules for where your ownership of a utility line begins and ends are fairly explicit.

Answer (score -2):

### It might be your wire or it might be the utility’s wire

Local law varies on this and you don’t say where you are. It’s also possible that it’s your wire but the utility is under contract to maintain it.

If it’s your wire, you can do what you like with it subject to licensing (some jurisdictions require a licence for comms work) and safety laws (like you can’t leave it where it will be a hazard).

If it’s not your wire then it’s not your wire and legally, you shouldn’t touch it. However, since it’s to be demolished, you’re unlikely to get into trouble if you do touch it.

Answer (score -3):

It's your house, your wire. If you want internet service and there isn't a wire, you'd either have to pay someone to install it, or convince them to do it for free. There is a point where it's not your wire, but that is outside, at the pole. If you climb the pole to cut the wire up high, you might damage the connector / wire that is not yours, but sorting that out is a DIY SE matter, not a Law SE matter. Though there may be some country where the government installs the wires so it's *not* actually your wire.

Comment: The folks at the DIY SE said it sounded like a question for Law SE... but I don't want internet service and this house is going to be demolished.